# Cedergren Dataset download in ubuntu

Tags: r, dataset, regression, glm

Has anyone used cedergren data set in Ubuntu. Im having problem downloading it as I hav Ubuntu OS. Its basically used for logistic regression

http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling289/cedegren-varbrul.html

would be using the glm func to see how it works on this dataset

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: what's your problem???  It looks like you're going to have to run the Windows version under WINE, as the referenced page suggests.  (`apt-get install wine`)

Comment: @BenBolker I think that would be for installing the goldvarb software I just want to read the data cedergren and use it in R(basically want to apply the glm func on it)

Comment: got it: http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/attachment/download/id_95/

Comment: ???? There's no need to install GoldVarb.

Comment: sorry.  A too-quick glance at the web site suggested that the data were in some format that was only GoldVarb-readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
> require(utils)
> inp <- read.fwf(file=url("http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling236/handouts/panama-mac.tok"), 
                 widths=rep(1, 5), colClasses=c("NULL", rep("factor",4) ) )
> str(inp)
'data.frame':   8955 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","L": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","A","d","m",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ V4: Factor w/ 4 levels "C","P","S","V": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V5: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

You can rename those columns and supply labels for the factors if needed to make this more self-documenting, but could be run as a glm dataset as is.